# How to work with UITextFields inside of UIActionsheet?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiactionsheet

i am new in iphone.i am doing reminder application to my project . i want get input values like reminder title and data&Time from uiactionsheet.i have created datepicker and uitextfield in actionsheet . The actionsheet appears with textfield.when i clicked on textfield,the keypad appears but not working means..when i was typed they are not visible in the textfield

```
-(void)btnSetRemainderTapped:(id)sender
{
UIActionSheet *menu = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select reminder date and time"
                                                  delegate:self
                                         cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                    destructiveButtonTitle:@"Save"
                                         otherButtonTitles:nil,nil];
 menu.tag =10;
[menu showInView:self.view];
menu.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

UITextField  *txtReminderTitle= [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0, 180, 280.0, 40.0)];
[txtReminderTitle setTag:99];
[txtReminderTitle setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[txtReminderTitle setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17]];
[txtReminderTitle setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];
[txtReminderTitle setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
txtReminderTitle.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
txtReminderTitle.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
txtReminderTitle.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
txtReminderTitle.delegate =self;
[menu addSubview:txtReminderTitle];

UIDatePicker *pickerView = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
pickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime;
pickerView.tag =9999;
[menu addSubview:pickerView];

CGRect menuRect = menu.frame;
NSInteger orgHeight = menuRect.size.height;
menuRect.origin.y -= 270; //height of picker
menuRect.size.height = orgHeight+270;
menu.frame = menuRect;

CGRect pickerRect = CGRectMake(20, 250, 280, 200);
pickerView.frame = pickerRect;
```

}

```
-(void) actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
  {
UIDatePicker *datePicker = (UIDatePicker *)[actionSheet viewWithTag:9999];
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
df.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterLongStyle;
[df setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
UITextField * txtReminderTitle = (UITextField *)[actionSheet viewWithTag:99];
   NSLog(@"%@",txtReminderTitle.text);  //it print null value
  }
```

I'm not sure why it's not accepting input from the keyboard. Any suggestions?

Comment: This is an abuse of `UIActionSheet`. This is not it's purpose. Do not use standard UI components in a way that they are not designed. What happens when Apple completely changes how a `UIActionSheet` works or looks in a future version of iOS? Create your own custom view for displaying what you need.

Comment: but wt u need to put UITextField in UIActionSheet ?? it very simple and pretty  to put it in UIAlertView.

Comment: why you not use Alert instead of UIActionsheet..?

Comment: @iPatel He also needs a `UIDatePicker`. You can't put that in a `UIAlertView`.

Comment: i have checked alertView and ViewController  working fine but my doubt is  can we implement textfield inside uiactionsheet?

Comment: @Ravindhiran A `UIActionSheet` is only for displaying a set of choices (buttons). It is not a general purpose control for showing arbitrary content. Use it only for its intended purpose. You can create your own custom view that slides up from the bottom like an action sheet if you wish. `UIAlertView` does support 1 or 2 text fields but no other custom content such as a date picker.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to enable text input in UITextField which is in UIActionSheet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089437/how-to-enable-text-input-in-uitextfield-which-is-in-uiactionsheet)

Answer (score 4):

I found that, when you add `UITextField` to `UIActionSheet` then `UITextField` is remain under the `UIActionSheet`. So you need to bring `UITextField` above `UIActionSheet` thats way
`[menu addSubview:txtReminderTitle];` does not work for `UITextField` to **input any text**.

Use following code for add `UITextField`:

```
UIWindow *appWindow = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
[appWindow insertSubview:txtReminderTitle aboveSubview:menu];
```

Only need to do changes in how to add `UITextField`.

Answer (score 0):

Use custom UIActionSheet . do like following
1) add new UIViewController
2) declare one UITextField

```
@interface ViewController  
{
            UITextField *TextField;

    }
```

3) add delegates of ActionSheet & TextField

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIActionSheetDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate> {

        UITextField *TextField;

    }
```

4)Now implement  methods

see this link just i see on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089437/how-to-enable-text-input-in-uitextfield-which-is-in-uiactionsheet)

Comment: @Ravindhiran The accepted answer in the posted link is what I am talking about. It is a custom class that does what you want without using a `UIActionSheet`. Please consider using that code as a basis for your solution.

Comment: k thanks,small doubt you  posted link why he implemented  @interface trialViewController : UIViewController <UIActionSheetDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate>   what is the need for UIActionsheetDelegate? he used instead of uiview

Comment: @Ravindhiran There is no reason at all that the custom view controller should adhere to `UIActionSheetDelegate`. That should be removed.