# UIAlertView displays textboxes and buttons

Tags: uialertview

I used the following code to create a `UIAlertView` and add some components on it but the result is at the image :(( (image is here : https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTg02.png)

```
-(IBAction)login:(id)sender
{
    UIAlertView *login = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle: @"Login first"
                                                   message:@"enter username and password please first" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel"otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];

k = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0, 70.0, 200.0, 25.0)]; //<< it also displays wrong without this line
k.text = @"";
k.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
k.clearButtonMode= UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
k.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet;
k.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;

p = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0, 100.0, 200.0, 25.0)];
p.text = @"";
p.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
p.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
p.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet;
p.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;

[login addSubview:k];
[login addSubview:p];
[login show];
}
```

Comment: you need to use UIPopoverController instead of UIAlertView

Comment: you can use customView to do it

Answer (score 1):

if you want to add multiple textField and Multiple Button on UIAlertView then follow the step :

**step 1 :**

```
@interface ViewController ()<UIAlertViewDelegate>
{
    UITextField *textFieldOne,*textFieldTwo,*textFieldThird;
}
```

**step 2 :**

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Multiple TextField" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"NO" otherButtonTitles:@"YES", nil];

    [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"CANCEL"];
     alert.delegate=self;

    UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    textFieldOne=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 0, 150, 20)];
    [textFieldOne setPlaceholder:@"First Name"];
    [myView addSubview:textFieldOne];

    textFieldTwo=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,25, 150, 20)];
    [textFieldTwo setPlaceholder:@"Middle Name"];
    [myView addSubview:textFieldTwo];

    textFieldThird=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,50, 150, 20)];
    [textFieldThird setPlaceholder:@"Last Name"];
    [myView addSubview:textFieldThird];

    [alert setValue:myView forKey:@"accessoryView"];
    [alert show];
```

**step 3 :**

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

    if([title isEqualToString:@"YES"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Button YES");
        NSLog(@"TextFiledOne Text = %@",textFieldOne.text);
        NSLog(@"TextFiledTwo Text = %@",textFieldTwo.text);
        NSLog(@"TextFiledThree Text = %@",textFieldThird.text);
    }
    else if([title isEqualToString:@"NO"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Button NO");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Cancel is click");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `UIAlertView` is no thought for additional text input. You could use instead a `UIActionSheet` as it is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089437/how-to-enable-text-input-in-uitextfield-which-is-in-uiactionsheet).

Answer (score 0):

Don't go for all the bluffs. Just use the following code:

```
[login setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput];
```

And to handle the inputs of the user, use this:

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if([[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text isEqual:@"UserName"]&&[[alertView textFieldAtIndex:1].text isEqual:@"PassWord"])
    {
        //do your stuff here
        [adminLoginButton setTitle:@"Logout" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [adminLoginButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Logout.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *errorMessage = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Authentication Error" message:@"Input is wrong" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [errorMessage show];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no point adding to the code that has already been added on here as it is good enough already and there are some good alternatives given. What I am going to do is tell you why you shouldn't be adding your own `UITextField`s to a `UIAlertView` using `addSubview:`.

Basically Apple have made the `UIAlertView` class to be used `as is` and the view hierarchy for this class is private.

> **Subclassing Notes**
>
> The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.

Subclassing note taken from [`UIAlertView` Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/index.html).

In essence what this means is that if you use the `addSubview:` method on a `UIAlertView` then you are in essence altering something that Apple as indicated as being private and your app would get rejected from the Apple App Review Process for rule **2.5**.

> **2.5**  Apps that use non-public APIs will be rejected

You might be asking yourself why does that method even exist then for `UIAlertView` surely because its there we can use it. Well **NO** the reason it is there is because the `UIAlertView` class is itself is a subclass of `UIView` which is where the `addSubview:` method is declared. Unfortunately there is no why to stop a instance of `UIAlertView` from actually calling that method. So what Apple have done is they have overridden the `addSubview:` method and all it does is it returns. So this method makes it do nothing and any views you pass to this method will never get added, as it never calls `[super addSubview:view];`.

So when it comes to `UIAlertView`s there are two things that you shouldn't be doing and these are:

1. **Subclass** `UIAlertView` like `@interface MYAlertView : UIAlertView` this is subclassing and is not allowed.
2. **Alter View Hierarchy** like `[alertView addSubview:view];`

However there is one point I should make, whilst we aren't allowed to subclass `UIAlertView` we are still allowed to make categories for it like `@interface UIAlertView (MyCategory)` as this is not classed as subclassing it is known as a class category or class extension (I've also heard it called a class provider before).

It should also be noted that if you are developing for `iOS8` and above you should be using `UIAlertController` as the `UIAlertView` has been deprecated.

> **Important:**
>
> UIAlertView is deprecated in iOS 8. (Note that UIAlertViewDelegate is also deprecated.) To create and manage alerts in iOS 8 and later, instead use UIAlertController with a preferredStyle of UIAlertControllerStyleAlert.

So I'd either use one of the custom classes mentioned in the other answers or move to use `UIAlertController` or if you have the time make your own custom alert view.

I hope this explanation helps you understand `UIAlertView`s more.