# Make UIAlertView stay

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

I have a `UIAlertView` that I implemented in `viewDidLoad`. I'm trying to make the `alertView` stay when the `otherButton` (`buttonAtIndex:1`) was selected. Here is my code:

```
UIAlertView *dialog = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title"
                      message:@"Message:"
                      delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                      otherButtonTitles:@"Done", nil];

[dialog setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput];
[dialog show];


- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 1) return;
    [alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:buttonIndex animated:YES];
}
```

When the second button was selected ("Done"), the `alertView` goes away. How can I make it stay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create your own alert view class that is NOT a subclass of UIAlertView. UIAlertView's documentation, it says under 'Subclassing notes:

*The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. (...)*

Above referenced in [`UIAlertView` Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/index.html) section marked **Subclassing Notes**

Comment: Yes totally this is exactly one valid way of doing it. I honestly can't believe that two answers on here are telling the OP to Subclass `UIAlertView` clearly they haven't read the Apple Documentation +1. PS I added like to reference I hope you don't mind

Comment: I just find it best to add the document you are referencing from then people can't question it or argue about it with you.

Answer (score -1):

You might have what you want [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2051969/2219009) :

> Subclass UIAlertView and then overload
>   -dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated:, e.g.

```
@implementation MyAlertView 
-(void)dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex animated:(BOOL)animated {
   if (buttonIndex should not dismiss the alert)
      return;
   [super dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:buttonIndex animated:animated];
}
@end
```

Comment: Same as other answer just no such a bad answer. Have you even read the Apple Documentation in regards to `UIAlertView`s? You should never subclass `UIAlertView` please read the apple docs https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/index.html and look at the section marked **Subclassing Notes** if you miss it though here it is `The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified` OP This is a bad answer never subclass `UIAlertView`

Comment: Instead of "can't believe that two answers on here are telling the OP to Subclass", could you explain why Apple doesn't recommend that ? Furthermore, that doesn't modify the view hierarchy, does it ?

Comment: read the documentation it clearly states `The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing` under the **subclassing notes** section. It is self explanatory, what don't you understand by it?

Comment: You don't answer my question. I read the doc and saw that, I'm just asking WHY we shouldn't, particularly if we don't modify the view hierarchy (except the fact that Apples tells not to do it)

Comment: Subclassing and altering the view hierarchy are two completely different thing. Altering the view hierarchy you are adding views to it by either using the `addSubview:` method or using the `setValue:forKey:@"accessoryView"` as for why you aren't allowed is beyond my knowledge and probably anyones on here so ask apple. As for subclassing which is being done in both answers this is just a no no as far as developers are concerned if you want to know why ask Apple again. Both though are classed as using a private API and would get rejected for that reason.

Comment: I'd also have a look at the answer I wrote here for a little better description on why http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16119132/uialertview-displays-textboxes-and-buttons/30774349#30774349